# Cookie Retrieval in GSP Not Working

Tags: grails, cookies, gsp

Grails 2.1.1

In my controller:

```
def someAction() {
   def projectVersionInstance = ProjectVersion.get(params.id)
   Cookie cookie = new Cookie("lastProjectVersion","${projectVersionInstance.id}")
   response.addCookie(cookie)
   .....
}
```

In my GSP:

```
<g:if test="${cookie(name: 'lastProjectVersion')}">
   ....
</g:if>
```

The content inside the `g:if` tag isn't showing up.  I even just tried the following:

```
<g:cookie name="lastProjectVersion" />
```

And I get nothing.  I can display it in the controller and I can see it in the browser cookie management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the problem too and it come from a redirect at the end of the method in controller.

When I used it, I lost all the cookies I set, but not the JSESSIONID one.

After googling, I found these help (http://www.zugiart.com/2011/04/http-redirect-and-cookies/).

When defining your cookie, set the path to '/' : cookie.path = '/'.

Now, you can redirect too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cookie is not available to the cookie method "cookie()" until the next http call. Why not you simply pass the cookie value from controller to gsp with a model var?

Comment: It doesn't matter how many times I refresh the page, the cookie is never available, according to the taglib, even though I know it is there.

Comment: if you comment //response.addCookie(cookie) and try to refresh the page?